# How to implement a Rich Text Editor in HTML?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, rich-text-editor

Here is the demo:

http://www.kevinroth.com/rte/demo.htm

when I use firebugs to inspect the source code, I see that it is iFrame only, but how can the iFrame have a text area behavior?? Any ideas on how to implement this? Thank in

Answer (score 9):

As I'm doing this for my job right now, I've done a small amount of of research. From what I have figured out, there are two ways to accomplish this:

### document.designMode

Using `document.designMode` in JavaScript which sets the whole HTML document to be editable.  As the whole HTML document is editable, presumably an `iframe` is needed to encapsulate the editing, so that the user can't edit any part of the page you don't want editing.

From what I can tell, the demo you linked and TinyMCE uses this method.

### contenteditable

The `contenteditable` HTML attribute is similar but doesn't require an `iframe` to be used. You add the attribute to a tag and all of the HTML within it becomes editable with a blinking cursor.

Here is a demo of it: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

---

#### Notes

- Personally I'll be looking at `contenteditable` for my task. Here is good overview and details on the topic: http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable
- As I say I have done limited research on this, so please help me correct any errors :)

Answer (score -1):

In that frame you can see a full HTML source that builds up something that *looks like* a text area + toolbar + stuff. A complicated Javascript is doing all the trick behind. E.g. if you select some text and make it bold with the toolbar than the script places `<strong>` tags around your text and so on..

Comment: but how the frame have the text area, I checked their source code using firebugs, it seems they don't have textarea on the frame.

Comment: I think it catches the keyboard events without any text area. The keypressed events are processed directly. However the code is compressed so hard to see the truth.

Comment: yes, the code is compressed, that's why I ask it on stackoverflow XD. but I don't think he/she works the keypressed events, because I see the cursor is blinking

Comment: You can easily unpack the richtext_compressed.js that can be downloaded from the site with http://www.strictly-software.com/unpacker

Comment: Sure its keypress event: h.addEventListener("keypress", geckoKeyPress, true)

Comment: but how the blinking cursor explain?

Comment: The `isContentEditable` CSS property is true on the IFRAME body. Please +1 me :-)

Answer (score -3):

Use http://www.tinymce.com/ It is the best rich editor out there. Works great with any browser and it has many many options. It's very easy to use. Just look at the examples and docs. It's included with many popular blogs and CMS.

Comment: I know there is rich text editor out there, but I would like to implement my own one. So, just wanna to know the idea behind.

Comment: He did not ask for other editors, he wants to know how does it work!

Comment: Oh, Ok. You must create editor's DOM dynamically. Make it works right with every browser is not trivial. I recommend you check at source code of some libraries, so you can make an idea.